# React-Apollo mutation data outside the function?

Tags: reactjs, graph, apollo, react-apollo

I have the following mutation

```
<Mutation mutation={LOGIN}>
    { (login, {data,loading,error}) => {
        if(loading)  return(<h1> Loading... </h1>);
        return(
            <button onClick={
                e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                    login({
                        variables: {
                            email: this.state.email,
                            password: this.state.password
                        }
                    }).then(() => this.context.login(
                        data.login.token, 
                        data.login.userId, 
                        data.login.tokenExpiration))
                }}>
                Login
            </button>
        );
    }}
</Mutation>
```

You can see, i call the login method onClick and after i use a `.then` block, however, it will throw an error because `data` object from the mutation above is undefined, how can i pass this data or make it available outside the mutation function? Or maybe pass them through props?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [event handler](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and pass arguments like this:

```
handleClick(event, login , data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    login({
       variables: {
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password
       }
    }).then(() => this.context.login(
      data.login.token, 
      data.login.userId, 
      data.login.tokenExpiration
    ))
}

...

render() {
  return(
    <Mutation mutation={LOGIN}>
    { (login, {loading,error,data}) => {
        if(loading)  return(<h1> Loading... </h1>);
        if(error) return(<p>{`Error : ${error}`}</p>);
        return(
         <button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, login, data)}>
           Login
         </button>
        );
    }}
    </Mutation>
  )
}
```

Comment: If i do it'll just same the same thing. Also, data will be undefined if i console.log it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a ternary operator to display the data when it exists?

```
<Mutation mutation={LOGIN}>
    { (login, {data,loading,error}) => {
        if(loading)  return(<h1> Loading... </h1>);
        return(
            <button onClick={
                e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                    login({
                        variables: {
                            email: this.state.email,
                            password: this.state.password
                        }
                    })

                       {data && () => this.context.login(
                        data.login.token, 
                        data.login.userId, 
                        data.login.tokenExpiration) }
                }}>
                Login
            </button>
        );
    }}
</Mutation>
```

Maybe in your case you shouldn't use the mutation component but the graphql hoc to be able to use the then syntax.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the response of the mutation is returned in the mutation promise so you can use it instead of trying to use the `data` in the mutation result.

```
login({
  variables: {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password
  }
}).then(response => {
  this.context.login(
    response.data.login.token, 
    response.data.login.userId, 
    response.data.login.tokenExpiration
  );
})
```